# Get ids from array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I want to select ids from observable
I have an array as below. Please help me to get the expected output.

```
const Input=[{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "My Choice 1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "text": "My Choice 2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "text": "My Choice 3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "text": "My Choice 4"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "text": "My Choice 5"
}];
```

Expected Result :

```
let selectedIds = [
      {id: "Choice", name: "2"},
      {id: "Choice", name: "3"},
      {id: "Choice", name: "5"}];
```

Comment: what you actually want to do??

Comment: Could you explain the relation between your Input and Output ? Are you filtering ? based on what criteria ? How do you transform your Input ?

Comment: id's should be unique, why are you keeping same id for every object ?

Answer (score 3):

Use array.map to transform the objects

```js
 const Input=[{
  "id": 1,
  "text": "My Choice 1"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "text": "My Choice 2"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "text": "My Choice 3"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "text": "My Choice 4"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "text": "My Choice 5"
}];

let Result = Input.map(choice => ({ id: "choice", name: choice.id }));
console.log(Result);
```

Comment: I want to send this result as a string to pass it as a variable in a query. let res = this.apollo.use('dataInsert').mutate({
      mutation: researchCreate,
      variables: {
        result: Result  }
    });                     where "result" accepts string.How will i pass the avove Result as string.

Comment: Use `const myString = Json.stringify(Result);`. `Json.stringify(jsonData)` converts Json data to a string and returns it

Answer (score 2):

```
let selectedIds = Input.map(item => 
{
  return {
    id: item.text,
    name: item.id
  };
})
```